# How to schedule an R web crawler script that stores data in SQL for weekly run?

Tags: r, automation, web-crawler, scheduling

I want to automate my R script that is essentially a web crawler, for weekly run even when system is locked. The crawler loads the data in a SQL db.

I tried scheduling the script for weekly run using the R-addin "taskscheduleR". Unfortunately a black screen pops up for a sec at the scheduled time but doesn't really starts the script.

Comment: There might not be enough information in your question to know the problem. For what it's worth, in my experience using `taskscheduleR` in Windows 10, a scheduled script would make a black DOS-like dialog box appear and then disappear while an R session would continue in the background. Did a task run in the background when it was supposed to? Would it be possible to run a simpler scheduled script first to make sure that's working, and then incrementally add aspects, like SQL db access?

Comment: Hi @JonSpring, I did just that in fact and wrote a script to print "Hello World". For this scheduled script also the black DOS-like screen pops up and disappears but it fails to print "Hello World in Console.

Comment: It will operate in its own session, so you won't see the results on your console if you have a session of R already running. Check out the documentation about setting up a log file: https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR

Comment: Yes @JonSpring, I can now see my results for "Hello World" script printed in a text file under extdata. Unfortunately the scheduler isn't behaving the same for web crawler. Do you recommend any changes to the script or any additional steps i can take for weekly scheduling? Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to know without any details about your script or what behavior you are seeing. You might try to start as basic as possible (e.g. just loading packages) and add incrementally to see where the problem is.

Comment: @JonSpring Right, I'll do that and see where its failing. It might be a silly question but how do I know if the libraries are loaded from the scheduled run?

Comment: `search()` will output a list of attached (ie loaded) libraries and R objects, like data frames.